# MariadB: using correlated subquery gives only one row

Tags: mariadb, correlated-subquery

I have two tables `c0` and `m0` which I merge using a left join. The result is a table with 13 rows. I would like to add the first date of the next 40 days windows. Here are the data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test0.c0;
CREATE TABLE test0.c0 (
  id      INTEGER
, cons_dt DATE
);

INSERT INTO test0.c0 VALUES
 ('1','2000-01-01')
,('1','2000-02-01')
,('1','2000-03-01')
,('1','2000-04-01')
,('1','2000-05-01')
,('1','2000-06-01')
,('1','2000-07-01')
,('1','2000-08-01')
,('1','2000-09-01')
,('1','2000-10-01')
,('1','2000-11-01')
,('1','2000-12-01')
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test0.m0;
CREATE TABLE test0.m0 ( 
  id        INTEGER
, start_dt  DATE
, atc       CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO test0.m0 VALUES
 ('1','2000-03-01','A')
,('1','2000-04-01','A')
,('1','2000-08-01','A')
,('1','2000-08-01','B')
,('1','2000-09-01','A')
,('1','2000-10-01','B')
;
```

And here is the code:

```
SELECT c.*, m.start_dt, m.atc
      , (SELECT MIN(c.cons_dt)
         FROM test0.c0 c2
         WHERE c2.id = c.id 
                   AND c2.cons_dt BETWEEN c.cons_dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND c.cons_dt + INTERVAL 40 DAY
         ) AS stop_dt
FROM test0.c0 c
LEFT OUTER JOIN test0.m0 m ON c.id = m.id AND c.cons_dt = m.start_dt
```

This is the output:

```
+----+------------+------------+-----+---------+
| id |  cons_dt   |  start_dt  | atc | stop_dt |
+----+------------+------------+-----+---------+
|  1 | 2000-03-01 | 2000-03-01 | A   | \N      |
+----+------------+------------+-----+---------+
```

I expected to get 13 rows with a stop date or without if the condition is not fullfilled. What's wrong with the code?
I know I could use windows function but this works not for this kind of data. Consider that this is a simplified dataset. The original has many ids and various atcs.

UPDATE 1:
Here are present a code which gives the correct result:

```
SELECT c.*, m.start_dt, m.atc, MIN(c2.cons_dt) AS stop_dt
FROM test0.c0 c
LEFT OUTER JOIN test0.m0 m ON c.id = m.id AND c.cons_dt = m.start_dt
LEFT JOIN test0.c0 c2 ON c.id = c2.id
                      AND c2.cons_dt BETWEEN c.cons_dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND c.cons_dt + INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY c.id, c.cons_dt, m.start_dt, m.atc
;
```

and here is the table I get and I expected:

```
+----+------------+------------+-----+------------+
| id |  cons_dt   |  start_dt  | atc |  stop_dt   |
+----+------------+------------+-----+------------+
|  1 | 2000-01-01 | \N         | \N  | \N         |
|  1 | 2000-02-01 | \N         | \N  | 2000-03-01 |
|  1 | 2000-03-01 | 2000-03-01 | A   | \N         |
|  1 | 2000-04-01 | 2000-04-01 | A   | 2000-05-01 |
|  1 | 2000-05-01 | \N         | \N  | \N         |
|  1 | 2000-06-01 | \N         | \N  | 2000-07-01 |
|  1 | 2000-07-01 | \N         | \N  | \N         |
|  1 | 2000-08-01 | 2000-08-01 | A   | \N         |
|  1 | 2000-08-01 | 2000-08-01 | B   | \N         |
|  1 | 2000-09-01 | 2000-09-01 | A   | 2000-10-01 |
|  1 | 2000-10-01 | 2000-10-01 | B   | \N         |
|  1 | 2000-11-01 | \N         | \N  | 2000-12-01 |
|  1 | 2000-12-01 | \N         | \N  | \N         |
+----+------------+------------+-----+------------+
```

I just want to understand why the subquery does not work. An interesting question would be also which performs better.

UPDATE 2: ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
slaakso indicated what is the problem. When ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled (it is the default) the engine restricted the use of aggregate function. Nevertheless, it is confusing since this works:

```
SELECT c.* ,m.atc ,m.start_dt 
     , (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM test0.c0 c2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN test0.m0 m2 ON c2.id = m2.id AND c2.cons_dt = m2.start_dt
        WHERE c2.id = c.id
        AND m2.atc <=> m.atc
        AND c.cons_dt > c2.cons_dt
        ) + 1 AS counter
FROM test0.c0 C
LEFT OUTER JOIN test0.m0 m ON c.id = m.id AND c.cons_dt = m.start_dt
ORDER BY m.atc, c.cons_dt, counter
;
```

and here is the output:

```
+----+------------+-----+------------+---------+
| id |  cons_dt   | atc |  start_dt  | counter |
+----+------------+-----+------------+---------+
|  1 | 2000-01-01 | \N  | \N         |       1 |
|  1 | 2000-02-01 | \N  | \N         |       2 |
|  1 | 2000-05-01 | \N  | \N         |       3 |
|  1 | 2000-06-01 | \N  | \N         |       4 |
|  1 | 2000-07-01 | \N  | \N         |       5 |
|  1 | 2000-11-01 | \N  | \N         |       6 |
|  1 | 2000-12-01 | \N  | \N         |       7 |
|  1 | 2000-03-01 | A   | 2000-03-01 |       1 |
|  1 | 2000-04-01 | A   | 2000-04-01 |       2 |
|  1 | 2000-08-01 | A   | 2000-08-01 |       3 |
|  1 | 2000-09-01 | A   | 2000-09-01 |       4 |
|  1 | 2000-08-01 | B   | 2000-08-01 |       1 |
|  1 | 2000-10-01 | B   | 2000-10-01 |       2 |
+----+------------+-----+------------+---------+
```

Why the first code does not work but the second? What makes these two codes distinct?

UPDATE 3: coming back to my initial problem

My code was wrong. MIN(c.cons_dt) in the subquery is wrong. Correct is MIN(c2.cons_dt). Now it gives the expected results. I suppose because c2.cons_dt belongs to the subquery.

```
SELECT c.*, m.start_dt, m.atc
      , (SELECT MIN(c2.cons_dt)
         FROM test0.c0 c2
         WHERE c.id = c2.id
               AND c2.cons_dt BETWEEN c.cons_dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND c.cons_dt + INTERVAL 30 DAY
         ) AS stop_dt
FROM test0.c0 c
LEFT OUTER JOIN test0.m0 m ON c.id = m.id AND c.cons_dt = m.start_dt
;
```

Here is an alternative:

```
SELECT c.*, m.start_dt, m.atc
      , (SELECT c2.cons_dt
         FROM test0.c0 c2
         WHERE c.id = c2.id
               AND c2.cons_dt BETWEEN c.cons_dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND c.cons_dt + INTERVAL 30 DAY
         ORDER BY c.id, cons_dt
         LIMIT 1
         ) AS stop_dt
FROM test0.c0 c
LEFT OUTER JOIN test0.m0 m ON c.id = m.id AND c.cons_dt = m.start_dt
;
```

Putting together: my initial code was wrong. Thanks to this I learnt  sql_mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Comment: You are missing `GROUP BY` from the outer query. Anyways, You might want to show the expected result and the logic behind it.

Comment: I delivered a code which gives the results I want. My question is mainly why this correlated subquery does not work. Whatever the subquery is, the main table should be selected and not only one row. 
I don't think that the outer query needs a group by.

Comment: It does. See https://dbfiddle.uk/q4bdhkeG. You should turn on the `only_full_group_by` option. Otherwise you get unexpected results like the one here.

Comment: @slaakso Thanks for solved my issue. Nevertheless why other similar subquery works (see update 2)?

Comment: @slaakso When I disable `only_full_group_by` with `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));` I still get one row.

Comment: In the other query, you are using `COUNT(*)` instead of `MIN(c.cons_dt)`. In the latter, you have a column from the outer query as a parameter to the aggregate function.

Comment: Regarding the other question, the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`-option forces you to write proper `GROUP BY` clauses and thus helps in avoiding errors. In older MySQL/MariaDB versions, this option was by default turned off, resulting in incorrect results for erroneous queries (wrong/missing `GROUP BY` statements). When the option is off and no `GROUP BY` is used, the database is free to pick any single row from the aggregate function instead of a value per defined group.

Comment: @slaakso If you put your comments in the answer box I can mark your answer. I suppose if I disable `only_full_group_by` it should give the expected rows. Why it didn't work using `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));` ?

Comment: `MIN(c.cons_dt)` doesn't make sense in the subquery. It should probably be `MIN(c2.cons_dt)`. In that case no `GROUP BY` is required and should not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mix normal columns with aggregate functions, you need to include the `GROUP BY` clause.

Make sure your server has `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode set as it will catch many of the incorrect queries.